# How to allow user to declare variable (Python)

Tags: python

How do I allow my program to let a user declare their own variables, on Python, like this:

```
var x = 20
```

Then possibly allow the user to make an if statement like this:

```
if x == 20:
    print("x is equal to 20")
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking about. What is the "user" in relation to the program? Is it a person typing stuff interactively or is it a programmer modifying the code to the program?

Answer (score 0):

In Python the `var` declaration is not necessary, just type

```
x = 20
```

Your conditional `print` statement should work just fine. This is a really basic question; I recommend you take a look at one of many free Python references, like [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/).

In summary, the code

```
x = 20
if x == 20:
    print("x is 20")
```

is what you're looking for. If you're using Python3, the parenthesis are mandatory, but not if you're using Python 2.

Comment: Yes I know, I want my user to be able to print a variable.

Comment: @MLCLOUD "print a variable" ? .. just write `print(x)` or alternatively `print('x is equal to', x)`